# Ref callback attribute is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've two examples using the `ref callback attribute`. The first on has a reference to the callback function. The second one has an arrow function declared as the value.

The first works as expected. But, the second one log a `null` on consecutive renders.

What is the reason for this?

Start typing inside the input box

**Example 1(this works fine)**

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.refCallback = this.refCallback.bind(this)
    this.state = {}
  }
  
  refCallback(el){
    console.log(el)
  }
  
  render(){
    return <input type="text"
      value={this.state.value}
      ref={this.refCallback}
      onChange={(e) => this.setState({value: e.target.value})}
      />
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

**Example 2 (this is not working)**

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {}
  }

  render(){
    return <input type="text"
      value={this.state.value}
      ref={(el) => console.log(el)}
      onChange={(e) => this.setState({value: e.target.value})}
      />
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: `<input type="text"
  value={this.state.value}
  ref="whatever"
  onChange={() => this.setState({value: this.refs.whatever.value})}
/>`

Comment: I know `ref string` will work. I need to know about `ref callback attribute`. React will deprecate `string ref` in future releases.

Comment: `<input type="text"
  value={this.state.value}
  ref={ref => this.whatever = ref}
  onChange={() => this.setState({value: this.whatever.input.value})}
/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been [discussed briefly on React's Github issues](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4533). I'll try to explain this, but it's kind of hard to put in words.

Since you're not calling a "smart" component method in your second example, the `console.log(el)` happens every time the component is re-rendered, which means it also calls when the specific node (in this case your input) is removed and rendered again, regardless if the `el` actually changed. When it is being removed by React it returns `null` because the element doesn't exist anymore, even if it's just for a fraction of a second. Seems like this is done for the sake of completion.

Here's a [tweet](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/584128974898536448) by Dan Abramov explaining this a little.

Comment: Looks interesting. Thanks for the links. Will approve it after sometime!

Comment: I've added a detailed answer below. Check if that is correct! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Adding to **Fabian Schultz**

This happens because in the first case, you're passing a reference of the function to the `ref`. During the initial render, the referenced function will be `instantiate` (a instance is created) and the `element` will be passed to that function. For the following renders(re-renders), this instance remains the same. So, React *won't* call this function as it is already being called.

But, in the second case, a arrow function is passed in as a value. So, for every re-renders the function will be passed again as the value. This results in two instances of arrow functions. One, from the previous render and the second from the recent render. Due to this, React `nullifies` the previous instance of the function. So, it returns `null` for the previous instance of the function and returns the `element` to the recent instance of the function.

**Point to take: Always use function reference for `ref`**

Hope this helps!

Comment: i tried it with this and it doesnt seem to fix anything.