# Children to children components communication

Tags: reactjs

I have 1 parent component name [Parent-1] and 1 child component name [Child-1]. Now, I have few more other components name [Other-1] and [Other-2].

Now i am passing [Other-1] and [Other-2] component to [Child-1] component. JSX is rendering correct. How can i access [Other-1/2] component functions from [Child-1] ? or How can i pass props to [Child-1] from [Other-1/2] ?

By using refs I am able to call the [Other-1/2] functions from [Parent-1] but I want to access from [Child-1]. I tried passing refs to [Child-1] like `<Child abc={() => this.refs.other1.hello()}/>` or `<Child abc={this.refs.other1.hello()}/>` but this is not working.

By using global Event Emitter way I am able to achieve solution to my above problem. But not sure if that's the appropriate way in React.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're not using the `refs` properly.

When you try to give an `arrow function` to refs it will sometime causes error due to the ref returning `null`. See [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40329950/ref-callback-attribute-is-not-working-as-expected) to find out why.

The example should help you understand `refs`

Hope this helps!

```js
class Others1 extends React.Component {
  log(){
    console.log('Hello from Others1')
  }
  render() {
    return <h1>Others1</h1>
  }
} 

class Others2 extends React.Component {
  log(){
    console.log('Hello from Others2')
  }
  render() {
    return <h1>Others2</h1>
  }
} 


class Child extends React.Component{
  other1Ref(el) {
    el.log()
  }
  other2Ref(el) {
    el.log()
  }
  render() {
    const Others1 = this.props.others1
    const Others2 = this.props.others2
    return (
      <div>
       <Others1 ref={this.other1Ref}/>
       <Others2 ref={this.other2Ref}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
  
}

class Parent extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return <Child others1={Others1} others2={Others2}/>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Additionally also got help from http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/

Comment: Although there is 1 more problem ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.something) always returns null when put in the the log() function and calling the log() function from Child

Comment: `this.refs.something` is called as string refs and those are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, There can be a case where we have to pass [Others1] and [Others2] as array of object say E.g.

```
class Others1 extends React.Component {
  log(){
    console.log('Hello from Others1');
  }
  render() {
    return <h1>Others1</h1>
  }
} 

class Child extends React.Component{
  other1Ref(el) {
    el.log();
  }

  render() {

    // 'i' need to be counter for eg. 0, 1, 2 ...
    const Others1 = this.props._array[i].type();
    Other1.other1Ref();

    return (
      <div></div>
    )
  }

}

let _array = [<Others1/>, ...];

class Parent extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return <Child _array={_array} />
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

By using .type() we will able to access Children function in case of array of objects/components