# Does React diff algorithm fails when using inline style

Tags: reactjs, inline-styles

While using react inline-style most people what they do is use object in styles attribute. for eg.

`<div style={{left: '54px', position: 'absolute'}}>
</div>`

Does this react diff algorithm fails over here as their is new object created everytime it re-renders.

Answer (score 2):

**YES, It will affect the diff algorithm**

Like you said you are creating an `Object` every time when you re-render.

But, when you do the following

```
const style = {left: '54px', position: 'absolute'}

<div style={style}></div>
```

you're passing a reference of `style` which remains the same throughout the component's lifecycle.

This is same for `arrow functions`. Read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40330731/4945468)

Comment: but `https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html` in              DOM Elements Of The Same Type  they told it only changes color attribute

Comment: I'm sure about it. But, I'm sure it consider it as a new object everytime.

Comment: if possible can you provide a working example so i can test it and approve the answer.