# Updating a component including a canvas with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

So I'm trying to modify the state of a component which contains a canvas element. The canvas itself should not update since the state affected does not affect the rendering of the canvas ?

```
import React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isPlaying: false
        }
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState({isPlaying: true});
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.ctx.fillRect(50,50, 100, 100);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div id='container'>
                <canvas width={900} height={500}
                    ref={r => this.ctx = r.getContext('2d')}
                    onClick={() => this.handleClick()} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Yet an error shows up when I trigger the event onClick of the canvas :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
at ref (App.js:52)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React component will re-render itself on any of its state property change. If you want control on this behavior, consider overriding `shouldComponentUpdate` method. If you return `false` from this method for any `state` condition, your component will not re-render for that condition.

Now, regarding the error, you should move the arrow function definition of `ref` into a function reference.

The reason is, arrow function will always be passed as new instance while re-rendering, while the function reference will be passed only once during first time render.

Read more from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40329950/ref-callback-attribute-is-not-working-as-expected) to know about this in more detail.

Your implementation should be as follows:

```
import React from "react";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isPlaying: false
    };
    this.setContext = this.setContext.bind(this);
  }

  setContext(r) {
    console.log(r);
    this.ctx = r.getContext("2d");
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    this.setState({ isPlaying: true });

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="container">
        <canvas
          width={900}
          height={500}
          ref={this.setContext}
          onClick={() => this.handleClick()} />
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

React docs [Refs Caveats](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#caveats) explain why you get the `getContext() of null`.

If the `ref` callback is defined as an inline function, it will get called twice during updates, **first with null** and then again with the DOM element. This is because a new instance of the function is created with each render, so React needs to clear the old ref and set up the new one. You can avoid this by defining the ref callback as a bound method on the class, but note that it shouldn’t matter in most cases. In your case it matters since you're calling `ctx.getContext("2d")`.

For getting rid of unnecessary renders of `canvas`, as already mentioned from other answers, encapsulate `isPlaying` in a `React.PureComponent` and communicate changes through an `onChange` prop.

```
import * as React from 'react';

export class Canvas extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    isPlaying: false
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    const isPlaying = !this.state.isPlaying;
    this.setState({isPlaying});
    this.props.onChange && this.props.onChange(isPlaying)
  }

  setRef = (ctx) => {
    this.ctx = ctx.getContext("2d");
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
  }

  render() {
    return (
     <canvas
        width={900}
        height={500}
        ref={this.setRef}
        onClick={() => this.handleClick()}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: "Cannot read property 'getContext' of null" has nothing to do with the onClick method, and the way he used handleClick you don't need to bind this because it's an arrow based function inside onClick

Answer (score 1):

Move the Canvas to it's own class based component then use **shouldComponentUpdate** as mentioned above, if you're rendering Canvas directly in the render method of this component it will re-render every time something is changed, but since you need the state to be updated you can not specify which elements need to be re-rendered unless these elements are own components and have should component update. You can then pass callback functions to get ref and onClick methods.